# My own ref command

Tags: ref

I would like to make my own \ref system.

I wrote \Problem command to denote the serial number and title. I want a new \myref command which yields the number and title by referencing the label. Could you help me?

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{1}

\def\Problem#1{
\noindent\textsf{\thecnt. #1}
\stepcounter{cnt}
}
\def\Answer#1{
\noindent\textsf{Ans. \myref{#1}}
}
\def\myref#1{
\ref{#1}
% I don't know.
}

\begin{document}

\section{Problems}

\Problem{Foo}\label{problem1}

\Problem{Bar}\label{problem2}


\section{Answers}

\Answer{problem1}

I want to display \textsf{Ans. 1. Foo}.

\Answer{problem2}

I want to display \textsf{Ans. 2. Bar}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter` to let TeX know that the counter should be referable. Is there a reason for not sticking to the regular `\label`-`\ref`-mechanism?

Comment: also you are missing `%` at the ends of lines in your macros, but I do not see why you can't use `\ref` here, `\myref` is just the same except that it adds space before and after the returned number.

Comment: @Tobi Thank you for teaching me \refstepcounter. I don't know how to use \label - \ref to display two entries. Could you let me know how to print the title by referencing?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for my humble source. :-(

Comment: Btw, instead of `\def` to define commands, LaTeX aficionados recommend using `\newcommand` as this checks to make sure you are not overwriting an existing command. It also has some other nice features; see, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191266/defining-macros-with-arguments/191271#191271. You can also use `\NewDocumentCommand` and friends from the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using theorems, so `\label` and `\ref` work out of the box and don't add unwanted spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{problem}
  {0pt}       % ABOVESPACE
  {0pt}       % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\sffamily} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  { }         % HEADSPACE
  % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC follows
  {\thmnumber{#2}. \protect\problemname}
\providecommand{\problemname}{}

\newtheoremstyle{answer}
  {0pt}       % ABOVESPACE
  {0pt}       % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\sffamily} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  { }         % HEADSPACE
  % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC follows
  {Ans.\ \protect\answername}
\providecommand{\answername}{}

\theoremstyle{problem}
\newtheorem{innerproblem}{}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Problem}[1]
 {%
  \renewcommand{\problemname}{#1}%
  \innerproblem
  \edef\@currentlabel{\theinnerproblem.\ \unexpanded{#1}}%
 }
 {\endinnerproblem}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{answer}
\newtheorem*{inneranswer}{}
\newenvironment{Answer}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\answername}{\ref{#1}}\inneranswer}
 {\endinneranswer}

\begin{document}

\section{Problems}

\begin{Problem}{Foo}\label{problem1}
Compute $1+1$.
\end{Problem}

\begin{Problem}{Bar}\label{problem2}
Compute $0+0$.
\end{Problem}

\section{Answers}

\begin{Answer}{problem1}
$1+1=2$.
\end{Answer}

\begin{Answer}{problem2}
$0+0=0$.
\end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier(?) way through [an answer for labeling a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230149/label-a-word-or-sentence).

```
\makeatletter
\def\Problem#1#2{
\stepcounter{cnt}
\noindent\textbf{\thecnt.} \textsf{#1}%
\def\@currentlabel{\thecnt. \unexpanded{#1}}\label{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\def\Answer#1{
\noindent\textsf{Ans. \ref{#1}}
}

\Problem{FOOBAR}{foobar}

\Answer{foobar}
```

Then, \ref{foobar} in \Answer command returns a concatenation of the counter and the title of label foobar.

It suffices for my work. But, this method does not seem to work well for hyperlink. As I click the title in Answer, it goes to the first page.