# How can I label an inline math formula/sentence/word?

Tags: cross-referencing

I tried to label a specific inline math formula in the paragraph. For a simple example,

```
\section{This is the third section}
$a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}$\label{formula:1}
Formula \ref{formula:1} is useful!
```

However, I found that \ref{formula:1} corresponds to the number of the section.

So the output by the above codes is 'Formula 3 is useful!' But What I want to label is $a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}$, and what I want to get is 'Formula 1 is useful!'. How can I realize it?

Comment: How about [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230174/121799)? Or just a plain `\hyperref` and `\hypertarget`?

Comment: @marmot [The answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230149/label-a-word-or-sentence/230174#230174) is exactly what I want! Thanks!

Comment: @Zarko Sorry for not saying clearly before, I mean neither \tag nor \eqno works in math mode. So I'm not able to use special tag for formula designation with them.

Comment: Glad to hear! What should we do, then? AFAIK the technically correct way is to close your question as a duplicate of the other one.