# How to make in RevTex format a reference for a specific word?

Tags: labels, ref

Hi I'm using a RevTex template and I would like to create a reference for a single word for instance 'molecule'. So i would like to use the reference for this word everytime I should write the word molecule. For example the phrase is:'The molecule is toxic'
I tried:

```
molecule\label{a}
The \ref{a} is toxic.
```

I also tried the solution here [Label a word or sentence?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230149/label-a-word-or-sentence),
but it doesn't work well, I observe these problems:
-It references the word but the word is in another color
-It changes also the color of other references made just with '\label{} + \ref{}, so the reference of equations for example appears red or green
-It changes also the dimension of my entire text
This is the code:

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setword}[2]{%
    \phantomsection
    #1\def\@currentlabel{\unexpanded{#1}}\label{#2}%
}
\makeatother
 \begin{document}
 \section{\label{sec:level1}example}
This is an example how to reference a word 'molecule'.
So I fixed the word '\setword{molecule}{Word:molecule}' and I try to use it again\\
The \ref{Word:molecule} is toxic
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq}
dV=Cd
\end{eqnarray}
As you can see in equation(\ref{eq})

\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq1}
dV=Cds
\end{eqnarray}
As you can see in equation(\ref{eq1})

\end{document}
```

here there's my initial test:

[image]

And this is what happen when I use the suggestion [Label a word or sentence?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230149/label-a-word-or-sentence):

[image]

Is there a way how to fix it?

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a helpful information. Please post a complete minimal example.

Comment: The colour comes from the option `colorlinks` passed to `hyperref`. Just remove it.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a suggestion how to solve the change of size of the font?

Comment: There is nothing changing the font there. You are just using an A6 paper size.

Comment: Sorry but I'm rookie and I started to use latex since few days. The problem is that this change is somehow related with the modification for referencing words (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230149/label-a-word-or-sentence)

Comment: No, `\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}` is not necessary; egreg used it only to have a more readable snapshot. Remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works and  now I understood  the problem.

Comment: Can we mark this question as answered by the linked one?

Comment: Sure, for me the problem is solved. thanks again